# JAVA - trouble with loading a object based file

Tags: java, file, object, save, load

i am having a little trouble reading a object from a text file as it preduces the following error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to stock.control.system.StockItem
```

which is this line;

```
StockItem result = (StockItem) ois.readObject();
```

below is how i save my file;

```
try { FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(StockItems); }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    }
```

and here is what i have done for far for loading the file back into a object ArrayList;

```
  try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        System.out.println("LOADING DATA ...");
        StockItem result = (StockItem) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
        System.out.println(result.getItemID() + ", " + result.getItemDesc()
            + ", " + result.getPrice() + ", " + result.getQuantity() + ", "
            + result.getReOrderLevel()); // used for testing
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StockArrayList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

if anywhere could educate me so it can be done correctly it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `StockItems`? Is this a `StockItem` instance?

Comment: You serialized an Object of type `StockItem[]` and want to cast the unserialized object to type `StockItem`? This must fail. Unserialize it as an array again.

Comment: It looks like you are writing an arraylist "StockItems" but trying to read a "StockItem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to assign the output to a array list in a tester class which was then in turn fed into a interface and from within the interface i had to assign it into another array list, this was how i fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file does not contain what you think it does. It contains an `ArrayList`, not a `StockItem`. Try taking the first element of the arraylist:

```
StockItem result = (StockItem) ((ArrayList)ois.readObject()).get(0)
```

and see what type that is.

Comment: Note that if it is an `ArrayList` of `StockItem`s you may not be done! You'd probably want to iterate through the list and process them all.

Comment: it contains; [Item ID = P123, Item Description = 1TB Hard drive, Price = 75.0, Quantity = 267, Re Order Level = 50] ill give the iterate over each object to save them now =)

Comment: What produced the file? If it wasn't an `ObjectOutputStream` fed a `StockItem`, Java won't reconstruct a string into whatever object you cast it to.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that what was written to the file is an ArrayList. 
Looks like that `StockItems` you write is `ArrayList<StockItem>`. When you read, you get the array list back, so you can't cast it to `StockItem`. You need to cast it to `ArrayList` and then iterate over the list and cast each element to `StockItem`.